# How to display monthly revenue splitting between new users, resurrected users, and churned etc users in sql?

Tags: sql

So say I have 3 fields in my table - month, user, and revenue. I am trying to build a table that shows me total revenue by month broken down by the revenue type - new (which means it's a user that spent for the first time)
- returning (which means it's a user that did not spend in the previous month but that spent in the past and spent in the month in question)
- expansion (which means it's a user that spent in the previous month but spent **more** this time)
- contraction (which means it's a user that spent in the previous month but spent **less** this time)
- churned (which means it's a user that spent in the previous month but not in this month...so this will actually be negative and will not add to or take away from the total revenue). So basically:
New+
Expansion+Resurrected+Contraction+Remaining+= Total then (Churned)

Exemplary table with the added fields to give a sense of the math
[image: This is just an exemplary table with the added fields to give a sense of the math]

I'm ultimately looking to build a stacked column chart like this one:
[image: I'm ultimately looking to build a stacked column chart like this one]

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you need to solve for

```
2+agoMo PriorMo  ThisMo
0       0        x       New
x       0        x       Returning/Resurected
?       w    <   x       Expansion
?       z    >   x       Contraction
?       y        0       Churned
?       x    =   x >0    Remaining
?       0        0       Sleeping
```

What have you coded already? what results are you getting?